# Cauchy Criterion - Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{\sqrt k}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{k}}{\sqrt k}$$

I have shown this converges uniformly in $[0,1]$:

But my working also implies $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{\sqrt k}$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$ but $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$ clearly diverges.

Define $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{k}}{\sqrt k} \forall x\in [0,1]$

I will show $S_n$ is uniformly cauchy on $[0,1]$

Now $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p}{\sqrt n}=0$ so using same argument as before $\exists N s.t. \forall n>N, \left|{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{p} $

Then $\forall x \in [0,1], \forall p$ and $\forall n>N$ we have:

$\left|s_{n+p}(x)-s_n(x)\right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{x^{k}}{\sqrt k}\right| ≤  \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\right| ≤\left|{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\right|+...+\left|{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\right|<p.\frac{\epsilon}{p} =\epsilon$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: We can't tell your mistake without seeing your work.

Comment: Takes a lot of time typing it up using latex so I have uploaded it here: http://oi66.tinypic.com/10fyjys.jpg

Comment: Basically the absolute value shows the non alternating series converges toofor x in [0,1].

Comment: But it doesn't converge for $x\in[0,1]$ in particular for $x=1$.

Comment: The alternating series converges uniformly for x in [0,1] and my working implies the non-alternating series does too

Comment: It would be much better if you copied that here. It is hard to read there. It appears as if your inequality is backwards in the sum. $\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: The modulus signs mean I can ignore the (-1)^(k-1) bit so get ∑ x^k/sqrt(k) and the rest of the working follows and so i conclude ∑1/root(k) converges but I know it doesn't

Comment: But you can't ignore the $(-1)^{k-1}$ part...

Comment: First of all is my working correct for the alternating series?
If it is then |(-1)^(k-1)| is just 1 so my working is the same for the non alternating case

Comment: As I feared; unless you at least copy the image to your question, or better write it in latex, the reviewers are going to vote to close, then possibly delete, your question.

Comment: Nice little trap: you showed $$\forall\epsilon\quad\forall p\quad\exists N\quad\forall n\geqslant N\quad\left|s_{n+p}(x)-s_n(x)\right|\leqslant\epsilon$$ but $(s_n(x))$ being a Cauchy sequence would mean $$\forall\epsilon\quad\exists N\quad\forall p\quad\forall n\geqslant N\quad\left|s_{n+p}(x)-s_n(x)\right|\leqslant\epsilon$$

Comment: I thought Andy broke the whole theory of analysis for a second there :P

Comment: That clears it up thanks

Comment: You are welcome. (And, @Namch96, thanks for the touch of humor...)

Answer (score 2):

To show that $S_n(x)$ is uniformly Cauchy on $[0,1]$, you need to find $N(\epsilon)$ (depending only on $\epsilon$) such that regardless of $p \ge 0$,

$$n > N \implies \sum_{n}^{n+p} < \epsilon$$

However, "your $N$", as it is now, depends on $p$; i.e, the bigger $p$ is, so does your $N$ have to be.

Comment: So is this correct for showing the alternating one converges:
Let $m>n$ and $x \in [0,1]$
$\left| s_m(x) - s_n(x) \right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{k}}{\sqrt k}\right|≤ \frac{x^n}{\sqrt n}≤ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$

So $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N s.t \forall n>N, \frac{1}{\sqrt n}<\epsilon$. And so $\forall m>n>N \left| s_m(x) - s_n(x) \right|<\epsilon$

Comment: @George Yes this is the simplest way to show this converges *when $x$ is nonnegative*, otherwise the argument fails (rightfully).

Comment: @George I think that works though you might have to do a little algebra work to show $|\sum_{k=n+1}^m(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{\sqrt k}| \le \frac{x^n}{\sqrt n}$. Intuitively, it's clear because $\frac{x^k}{\sqrt k}$ is decreasing and so the "partial sum" 'zig-zags' up and down but is always less than the initial value in terms of absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\le\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}}=\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{m}\right)\le\sum_{k=m}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\le2\left(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m-1}\right)
$$
No matter how big $m$ is, you can't bound the sum for all $n$.

Your argument seems to indicate that for all $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is an $m$ so big that
$$
\sum_{k=m}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\le\varepsilon
$$
for all $n\ge m$.

---

Now that I can read your answer better, the problem with your answer is that $p$ should not be dependent on $n$. That is, for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, there must be an $N$ (dependent on $\varepsilon$) so that for any $n\ge N$ and any $p\ge0$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right|\le\varepsilon
$$

---

Let me expand on what I have said in the last section.

What you have shown that for a fixed $p$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}=0
$$
and this is true. However, this is not sufficient to show that
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}
$$
is a Cauchy sequence. To show that $s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, you need to show that for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is an $M$ so that for all $n\ge m\ge M$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|s_n-s_m\right|
&=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\right|\\
&\le\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$
Your proof only shows this for $n-m\le p$.

Comment: So is the google book method wrong?

Comment: I doubt it. What method would that be?

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cJa2r_v5L84C&pg=SL18-PA151&lpg=SL18-PA151&dq=exponential+series+convergence+uniformly&source=bl&ots=S2oHPx4xVX&sig=tNXHYdblC9KU0yK1qbe2LwgiXd8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis-_2QhqXJAhXC1hQKHdA2CT44ChDoAQhCMAc#v=onepage&q=exponential%20series%20convergence%20uniformly&f=false

Comment: Does this answer the question "Where is my mistake?"?

Comment: So I did it the first way u suggested and the book did it the right way?

Comment: @Did: I believe it does since his argument, which was not easy to follow from the image, seemed to show that $\sum\limits_{k=m}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}$ could be made as small as desired by making $m$ large enough.

Comment: No, you showed that the conclusion the OP reached is wrong, which the OP was already aware of and which does not explain their mistake.

Comment: @Did: I was showing that the sum he was saying could be made arbitrarily small could not be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Did: I have expanded on my last section, added after [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MGkP1.jpg) was replaced by latex. [Before the latex was added](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1541947/3), all I could show was that the sequence was not Cauchy, which points out which step in the proof is wrong. After the latex was added, I could improve my answer to show why that step was wrong.

Comment: Showing *why* something is wrong is not the same as simply stating that something is wrong. Looking at *why* it is wrong, one can often determine *what* they did wrong. However, as soon as I could easily read the question, I showed *what* was wrong.

Comment: @robjohn Three rather contorted comments to basically confirm the point I made seem more than enough.